# Why would this be a deterministic context free language? $L = \{a^n b^n | n>0 \}$ $\cup$ $\{ a^n b^{2n} | n < 100 \}$

Tags: automata, pushdown-automata

so the book that I'm reading says this is a deterministic context free language 
 $L = \{a^n b^n | n>0 \}$ $\cup$ $\{  a^n b^{2n} | n < 100 \}$

But i think this is wrong Because :

at the beginning of building the DPDA, we have to decide whether we should go with the first one or the second, and considering both of them start with a there is just no way we could build a DPDA right?? or am i wrong?

i also tried solving this by first building the $a^nb^n$ and then going for the second one if the stack is not empty, but still couldn't come up with anything, i tried putting 2 a's for every a input but didn't work

so how is the book saying this can be build with a DPDA?

Also i have to say I KNOW that non infinite languages are regular, but this one is not infinite!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can create 100 states that push two $a$'s onto the stack for every $a$, and then pop these $a$'s for every $b$. In the event of getting to the 100th state, when you read the 101st $a$, pop 100 $b$s from the stack and continue as you would for the first language alone.

Comment: Yes i tried doing that but doesn't work, because for example if the input is $a^{20}b^{20}$ then after reading all the a's and pushing 40 a's into stack and then popping 20 a's by reading all the b's the stack won't be empty and then we won't accept this string

Comment: So you wanna write a DPDA that accepts by empty stack, not by final state? If you just wanna show that this language is deterministic, it's enough to build a DPDA that accepts by final states.

Comment: No it doesn't matter that its accepting by final state or not, it just needs to be deterministic, but using the method of pushing 2 a's for every one a input doesn't work in either way.

Comment: Could you give an example string that doesn't work?

Comment: Maybe i'm not getting how you build the machine, can you please explain how it would work for $a^2b^2$ ?

Comment: When you have $a^nb^n$ with $n < 100$ you can do it in a FA style, you build 100 states as said, when you read the first $b$ you go out of this stream of states, and go for a state that represents "I need to recognize $n$ $b$'s", you'll have also 100 of these states. While you go through these states, down to the state "I need to recognize $0$ $b$'s", you pop the stack. This last state will be a final state, if you continue to read $b$'s, you go to another state that continues to pop the stack, and only get out of it when the stack is empty, to a final state.

Comment: Now i get it thank you.. but i think we should not push 2 a's in the first 100 states and 1 is enough considering after that its either $a^nb^n$ or reject

Comment: Yeah, that way we don't need to pop 100 $a$'s too